# Simple HTML Dom PHP RECURSION Error in return value

Tags: php, dom, recursion

I am using Simple HTML Dom, trying to get strings from a website. When I print out $title[0] within the function it shows just one string, but when I safe it in the return array and print out the return value, I receive a never ending text with *RECURSION*. 
I don't understand why it would work with the second variable $oTitle.

```
<?php
include 'scripts/simple_html_dom.php';
    function getDetails($id) {
        $url = "http://www.something.com";
        $html = file_get_html ( $url );
        $title = $html->find('span[itemprop=name]'); 
        print_r($title[0] . PHP_EOL); //prints out the correct title
        $oTitle = "Something"; //there is also code for this variable but it works as it should
        $details = array("Title" => $title[0], "Original Title" => $oTitle);
        return $details;
        flush ();
    }
$values = getDetails($number);
print_r($values); //code breakes here
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

As I can see, you're using this parser.

In order to get HTML content you should use something like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

In order to drop content, you should use something like this:

```
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

Try this code:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    function getDetails() {
        $url = "http://www.godaddy.com";
        $html = file_get_html ( $url );
        $title = getTitle($url); 
        echo $title; //prints out the correct title
        $oTitle = "Something"; //there is also code for this variable but it works as it should
        $details = array("Title" => $title, "Original Title" => $oTitle);
        return $details;
        flush ();
    }

    function getTitle($Url){
        $str = file_get_contents($Url);
        if(strlen($str)>0){
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
            return $title[1];
        }
    }

$values = getDetails();

print_r($values); //code breakes here
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out soon, but I also got it working. I had to explode the string. So I guess that is similar to your method.